# Verify User from Android on Server-Side

Tags: php, android, google-plus

My Problem is the following:

---

> **1.** The User signs-in on the Android App using the Google+ API
>
> **2.** The User wants to submit content (e.g. a video), so he calls a
>   PHP from the App script with all the post variables (video_name,
>   creator, video_description, video_url)
>
> **3.** The Server stores everything in a MySQL Database

---

The Problem is the Part in 2. when the Server stores the "**creator**" name

---

**Creator** = Google Plus Name

---

Because someone could decompile the App and build the POST request with custom POST variables so the "hacker" could enter any name as the creator name.

**How** can I prevent that and/or is there any workaround to pass the Username to the Server when the user is only authenticated in the Android App and not authenticated on the Server Side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good approach would be to submit the login details to the server too which in your case is in step #2, and do one more authentication there. I suppose you are going to use php on your server so please take a look at the following page, which i believe is what you need:
https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/client-to-server-flow

Once you send the token, you need to do verification:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/token-verification

Even more details here:

https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-verifytoken-php